# FQL returning different results when queried from APP

Tags: php, facebook, stream, facebook-fql

I have a process which scrapes the stream table periodically for given users, importing any new comments or posts which have come in.  When I test my query using the facebooks fql.query link, the correct results are listed. For example:

SELECT post_id, app_id, actor_id, created_time, updated_time, message, comments, app_data, likes, attachment, permalink FROM stream WHERE source_id = "652904096" ORDER BY updated_time DESC LIMIT 0, 20

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20post_id,%20app_id,%20actor_id,%20created_time,%20updated_time,%20message,%20comments,%20app_data,%20likes,%20attachment,%20permalink%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id=652904096%20ORDER%20BY%20updated_time%20DESC%20LIMIT%200,%2020&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The first result is from earlier today.

But when I use my app and the php sdk, with the same query and access token, the first result is from December 23rd

Here is how I am calling the query from my App

```
$result = $fb->api(array(
    "method"=>"fql.query",
     "query"=>$query,
     "access_token"=>$oauth_token
 ));
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be occurring? I have added debug statements to the PHP SDK to confirm that the query and access tokens are the same.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! working on it at the moment.
Did you find what was the issue? It's not a cache problem for sure.

Comment: I switched to using the Graph API to query FQL and that seems to have solved my issue.  graph.facebook.com/fql?q=YOUR_QUERY

Comment: I'm already using the graph api, but still don't get the same results with the different 2 different tokens

Comment: That is intended.  My issue was with the same access token returning different results.

Answer (score 0):

If both the query & the access tokens are the same, there's some caching happening in the API you're using.  Have you tried using the Javascript SDK?  You can give it a quick test at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/.

Comment: There is no caching occurring in my app, and looking at base_facebook.php I cannot see any place where caching would occur.

Comment: Did the Javascript SDK return the old or new results?

Comment: I didn't even try the javascript SDK because it wouldn't solve my issue.  I need this to be a server side call.

Comment: All I was hoping for was a verification from you that the js sdk works so you knew whether or not to file a bug with Facebook since the server-side wont work like the client side. :( Oh well.